# jquery .hasClass not working at it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i have some checkboxes with different backgrounds on label. Tables with 4,6,8 seats. When i select a table let's say with 8 seats i want to change the background image with another image my case blue image coresponding to the eight bg img. I'm trying to that with hasClass selector but it's always getting the first if even if there is no class "four" and it's "eight".
Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".table").change(function(){
    if ($( ".table_bg" ).hasClass( "four" ))
    {
  var c = this.checked ? "url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg2.png)" : "url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg.png)";
    }
    else if($( ".table_bg" ).hasClass( "six" ))
    {
    var c = this.checked ? "url(http://rezerv.city/images/table6_bg2.png)" : "url(http://rezerv.city/images/table6_bg.png)";
    }
    else if($( ".table_bg" ).hasClass( "eight" ))
    {
    var c = this.checked ? "url(http://rezerv.city/images/table8_bg2.png)" : "url(http://rezerv.city/images/table8_bg.png)";
    }
  $(this).parent().css("background-image", c);
});
</script>
```

html

```
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_8 eight" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table8_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="64" id="1" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>1</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">8 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_8 eight" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:215px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table8_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="65" id="2" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>2</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">8 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_8 eight" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:390px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table8_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="66" id="3" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>3</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">8 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_6 six" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:197px;margin-left:0px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table6_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="67" id="4" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>4</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">6 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_4 four" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:197px;margin-left:215px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="68" id="5" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>5</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">4 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_4 four" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:197px;margin-left:390px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="69" id="6" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>6</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">4 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_4 four" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:197px;margin-left:565px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="70" id="7" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>7</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">4 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_6 six" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:354px;margin-left:0px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table6_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="71" id="8" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>8</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">6 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_4 four" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:354px;margin-left:215px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="72" id="9" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>9</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">4 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_4 four" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:354px;margin-left:390px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="73" id="10" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>10</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">4 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_4 four" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:354px;margin-left:565px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="74" id="11" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>11</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">4 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_6 six" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:511px;margin-left:0px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table6_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="75" id="12" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>12</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">6 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_4 four" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:511px;margin-left:215px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="76" id="13" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>13</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">4 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_4 four" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:511px;margin-left:390px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="77" id="14" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>14</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">4 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_4 four" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:511px;margin-left:565px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="78" id="15" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>15</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">4 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_6 six" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:708px;margin-left:0px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table6_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="79" id="16" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>16</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">6 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_4 four" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:708px;margin-left:175px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="80" id="17" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>17</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">4 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_6 six" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:708px;margin-left:350px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table6_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="81" id="18" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>18</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">6 pers</h5>
        </label>
        <label class="table_bg table_bg_4 four" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover"   data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:708px;margin-left:525px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="82" id="19" name="table[]" class="checkbox" ><h4>19</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">4 pers</h5>
        </label>
```

Comment: i added the html, sry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
if ($( ".table_bg" ).hasClass( "four" ))
```

You are selecting ALL of the .table_bg elements and the hasClass method will then test to see if *any* of them have the class called "four".

What you most likely want is just to test the parent element of the checkbox as below. 
When the checkbox changes it will test to see whether it's parent element has the numbered classes and will return the url based on that.

```js
$(".table").change(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass("four")) {
    var c = this.checked ? "url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg2.png)" : "url(http://rezerv.city/images/table_bg.png)";
  } else if ($(this).parent().hasClass("six")) {
    var c = this.checked ? "url(http://rezerv.city/images/table6_bg2.png)" : "url(http://rezerv.city/images/table6_bg.png)";
  } else if ($(this).parent().hasClass("eight")) {
    var c = this.checked ? "url(http://rezerv.city/images/table8_bg2.png)" : "url(http://rezerv.city/images/table8_bg.png)";
  }
  $(this).parent().css("background-image", c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="table_bg table_bg_8 eight" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover" data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table8_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
  <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="64" id="1" name="table[]" class="checkbox">
  <h4>1</h4>
  <h5 class="nr_pers">8 pers</h5>
</label>
<label class="table_bg table_bg_8 eight" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover" data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:215px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table8_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
  <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="65" id="2" name="table[]" class="checkbox">
  <h4>2</h4>
  <h5 class="nr_pers">8 pers</h5>
</label>
<label class="table_bg table_bg_8 eight" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover" data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:390px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/table8_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
  <input class="table" type="checkbox" value="66" id="3" name="table[]" class="checkbox">
  <h4>3</h4>
  <h5 class="nr_pers">8 pers</h5>
</label>
```

Comment: it's working thnx, but why it didn't work with class selector?

Comment: As I said, the class selector was selecting all of the table_bg matches, not just the parent of the checkbox that had changed. jQuery selectors return arrays of all the matches and the functions tend to work on all elements in the array, not just the one we'd like it to.